# How to read serial port data in DOS environment

Tags: c, dos

I'm working on DOS related project. I want to read the data from serial port in DOS using C.

Comment: [Serial programming in C , in DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609210/serial-programming-in-c-in-dos)

Answer (score 1):

I remember using a product called Async Pro in the good old days. It provided libraries to link against in Turbo Pascal if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

DOS called the serial port the COM port. Unfortunately you cannot use it as a file name in C like in Linux, while in the DOS prompt you can use COM1 to access it. I assume you have Turbo C (do we have gcc for DOS? probably not), you will need some "BIOS" library to use the COM port. I remember I wrote a program accessing the parallel port (LPT1) many years ago and the interface are roughly the same. [This](http://www.ontrak.net/c.htm) is the link that I found to be closest to my memory, and the code is as follows:

```
#include <sdio.h>
#include <bios.h>
#define com1 0
#define settings (0xE3)
main ( )
{   /* declare PORTA and DOUT as integer numbers */
    int PORTA,DOUT ;
    /* set DOUT to integer 255 */
    DOUT=255;
    /* configure com1 9600 baud, 8 bit words, no parity */
    bioscom (0,settings,com1);
    /* send CPA00000000 command to ADR101 on com1 */
    fprintf (stdaux,"CPA00000000 \xD");
    /* send MAddd (ddd=DOUT) command to ADR101 on com1 */
    fprintf (stdaux,"MA %d \xD",DOUT );
    /* send PA command to ADR101 on com1 */
    fprintf (stdaux,"PA \xD");
    /* initialize com1 buffer */
    fscanf (stdaux,"%d",&PORTA );
    /* print data on screen */
    rewind (stdaux);
    /* read data from com1 and store at address of PORTA */
    printf ("PORT A is %d DECIMAL \n",PORTA);
}
```

Comment: DJGPP is available for DOS which is an old port of gcc.